# How to find out which row was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i generate a Table with javascript and now i wont to find out which row and column the user has clicked?

Here are my function for the table:

```
function doNextSteps() {

    removeAustriaFromCountries();

    //insert table
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute('id', 'matrixTable');
    table.setAttribute('class', 'jbiTable');

    // insert MATRIX row
    var matrixRow = table.insertRow();
    var cell = matrixRow.insertCell(); // left column for countries
    cell.setAttribute('class', 'jbiMatrixCell');
    cell.setAttribute('colSpan', departments.length + 1);
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("MATRIX"));

    // insert departments row
    var departmentsRow = table.insertRow();
    var cell = departmentsRow.insertCell(); // left column for countries
    cell.setAttribute('class', 'jbiBlankCell');

    for (var i = 0; i < departments.length; i++) {
        var cell = departmentsRow.insertCell();
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(departments[i].name));
        cell.setAttribute('class', 'jbiDepartmentCell');
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        var countryRow = table.insertRow();
        var cell = countryRow.insertCell(); // left country column
        //cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countries[i].name)); 
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "example.com + flags[i].name";
        cell.appendChild(img);
        cell.setAttribute('class', 'jbiCountryCell');
        for (var j = 0; j < departments.length; j++) {
            var cell = countryRow.insertCell();
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = "https://intranet.windkraft.at/OrganisationManual/Documents/Kreis.jpg";
            img.onclick = function () {
                window.location.href = "example.com" + pdfFiles[i].name;
            };
            cell.appendChild(img);
            cell.setAttribute('class', 'jbiCircleCell');
        }
    }


    $("#divTable").append(table);

}
```

The table gets generated and now i want to know in which header and in which column the user has clicked. With that information i want to make a new query to get files dynamically displayed in the Table. Any help would be great. And thanks for your Help.

Comment: you can set data attributes e.g. `data-row="1" data-column="4"` in your loop for the elements. When clicked, you can simply fetch this value and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index of the row, you can use this code in your event listener function:

```
function onClick() {
  var cell = this;
  var row = cell.parentNode;
  var cellIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(row.children, cell);
  var rowIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(row.parentNode.children, row);

  // do stuff with rowIndex, cellIndex
  // rowIndex is the row number starting with row 0
  // cellIndex is the column number starting with column 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parentNode.rowIndex` & `cellIndex` to get the cell & rowIndex

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.parentNode.rowIndex,' ',e.target.cellIndex);
 }, false);
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/rahz7vav/)